# jfreeChart regression line realtime Day axis

Tags: java, date, graph, jfreechart

i am trying to plot a regression line on some data that is coming in every half second. I am currently plotting the data in realtime no problem. The data is being read by a thread and the main thread is handling refreshing the graph.
The data is a value on the y axis and "Day" (jfreeChart object "Day") on the x axis.

I have set it up in the thread listener to calculate the coefficients if the number of data points is greater than 1, it also then adds the dataSet to the mainPlot on this condition. So this is in the thread listener

```
if (++count > 1){
        double[] coefficients = Regression.getOLSRegression(TimeSeriesCollection, 0);
        mainPlot.setDataset(1, regressionData);
}
```

This is outside of the thread listener, next to the setup of the graph. The data, notice is coming from a timeSeriesCollection. The It does sort of plot, but sticks all the data at 1970, which means the rest of the data (which occurs in 2012) is bunched up to the right.

```
Function2D curve = new LineFunction2D(coefficients[0], coefficients[1]);
XYDataset regressionData = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(curve,
        2.0, 11.0, 100, "Fitted Regression Line");
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer2 = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer(true, 
        false);
renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
mainPlot.setRenderer(1, renderer2);
```

The problem is how to get it to understand the TimeSeries x axis data is "Day" objects and plot it at the correct place on the graph.
Has anyone managed to do this? When I plot the data "straight up, i.e without trying to do regression on it, just a line graph it plots beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

I used TimeSeries Chart for data and for regression line. So both charts are created by `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(...)`

Comment: You couldnt throw me  a slightly larger bone could you? The data I am trying to plot the regression line for IS in a timeSeriesCollection, and therefore a timeSeries. So by your message it sounds like there is a certain type of chart I should be plotting it on??? My chart is:


`JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(stockSymbol, null, mainPlot, false);
  ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
  chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));`
thanks

Comment: The simple way how to create TimeSeries Chart is: `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("", "", "",   dataset, false, false, false);` where `dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection()`. Then you add main graphic and regression line to dataset like `dataset.addSeries(timeSeries)`. And you need to fill your timeSeries (constructor: `new TimeSeries(title)`). Add `TimeSeriesDataItem` to timeSeries.

Comment: To build regression line create new timeSeries and new points using formula: `y = a+bx` where `a` and `b` are your `coefficients`.